# Deflate on WampServer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, deflate

I'm using deflate in a .htaccess-file. But this does not work in WampServer:

```
# deflate depending on filetype
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-shockwave-flash
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you might want to ask this on superuser.com or serverfault.com

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/598306/deflate-on-wampserver